# Is there a longitude or latitude function in HTML

Tags: html, latitude-longitude

I’m a beginner so the answer might be fairly obvious, see his creation on https://codpen.io/johan-tirholm/pen/JjoXJNg
I know it is not a problem with the website itself, and I don’t think there is a pre-existing longitude and latitude function. If that’s the case, I don’t know how to make those functions due to lack of experience. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API?

Comment: No, I mean location on a sphere

Comment: I just realized that I made a spelling mistake on the code pen website but if you check out his globe he uses a latitude and longitude to specify points on a sphere with out creating a function.

Comment: Hypertext Markup Language is the standard markup language for documents designed to be displayed in a web browser

Comment: @DecDDM Add the code you are working on And be very specific with your question, do not Just Add the link.

Comment: HTML has no functions, only declarative mark up

Answer (score 0):

@DecDDM

Please try this code,To use of longitude or latitude function in HTML

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I wanted to show the code so far... I used SCSS, HTML, and JS...